# 24 hour time not formatting date properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, formatting, nsdate, nsdateformatter

Below is the code I have.

```
mmDD = [[catererSQLArray objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"mmdateNTime"];
NSLog(@"mmDDmmDDmmDDmmDD===%@", mmDD);
NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"EE dd MMM yyyy hh:mm aa";
NSDate *yourDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:mmDD];
NSLog(@"yourDate==%@", yourDate);
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm";
mmDD = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:yourDate];
NSLog(@"mmDDmmDD==%@", mmDD);
```

Input for `mmDD` is `Fri 31 Oct 2014 04:00 PM`

When I run above code in 12-hour format I get below.

### 12-hour format

```
mmDDmmDDmmDDmmDD===Fri 31 Oct 2014 04:00 PM
yourDate==2014-10-31 13:00:00 +0000
mmDDmmDD==2014-10-31 16:00
```

When I run above code in 24-hour format I get below.

### 24-hour format

```
mmDDmmDDmmDDmmDD===Fri 31 Oct 2014 04:00 PM
yourDate==(null) <-----<-----<-----<-----<-----<-----
mmDDmmDD==(null) <-----<-----<-----<-----<-----<-----
          ^^^^^^
```

Any idea why & what is the solution to resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set the locale that support 24 hour clock.
Try the following:

```
NSLocale *enUSPOSIXLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
[dateFormatter setLocale:enUSPOSIXLocale];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm";
mmDD = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:yourDate];
NSLog(@"mmDDmmDD==%@", mmDD);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the locale of your `dateFormatter`.  By default it is the user's locale, and their user defaults overrides the format you have specified.  See this [technical note](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1480/_index.html).